# Node JS Post Request Results in Heroku Critical Error Request Timeout (503)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, fetch-api, http-status-code-503

**Background**: I have two apps. One that is an Express Node application connected to a Mongo database. The other is a basic web application that makes `POST` requests to the Node application via the Fetch API to get data from Mongo.

**Issue**: After making `POST` requests I receive this error below in my basic web application's console. However, in my Heroku console it states that the `503` error is an `H12 - Request Timeout`.

> Fetch cannot load (node app url).  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin (basic web app url) is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The `POST` request does seem to work and the data is saved into Mongo but this error is being marked as a "Critical Error" in Heroku and is quite annoying.

**Express Node App Code**

In my `app.js` file I have set the correct headers to ensure that other applications can make requests from different origins

app.js

```
// Add headers so we can make API requests
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

routes/api/api.js

```
router.post('/users/:url/upload-csv/:csv_name', (req, res) => {
  let csv_name = req.params.csv_name;
  let csv_string = csv_name+req.body.csv_string;

  User.findOne({url: req.params.url})
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.csv_files.length === 0) {
        user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      } else {
        let foundExistingCSV = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < user.csv_files.length; i++) {
          if (user.csv_files[i].includes(csv_name)) {
            foundExistingCSV  = true;
            user.csv_files[i] = csv_string;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!foundExistingCSV) user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      }
      user.markModified('csv_files');
      user.save();

      res.status(204);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400);
    });
});
```

**Basic Web App Code**

`POST` request I am making

utils.js

```
utils.exportToMongo = functions(table, name) {
  var exportPlugin = table.getPlugin('exportFile');
  var csv_string   = exportPlugin.exportAsString('csv');

  // Upload the CSV string and its name to Users DB
  fetch(`${utils.fetchUserURL()}/upload-csv/${name}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({csv_string: csv_string}),
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    })
  }).then((res) => {
    return {};
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return {};
  });
}
```

How can I remove the `503` error? It seems like there might be something that I need to add to my `POST` request in my Express application to handle request timeouts. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `return` and use change `status` to `sendStatus` like so?

```
router.post('/users/:url/upload-csv/:csv_name', (req, res) => {
  let csv_name = req.params.csv_name;
  let csv_string = csv_name+req.body.csv_string;

  return User.findOne({url: req.params.url})
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.csv_files.length === 0) {
        user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      } else {
        let foundExistingCSV = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < user.csv_files.length; i++) {
          if (user.csv_files[i].includes(csv_name)) {
            foundExistingCSV  = true;
            user.csv_files[i] = csv_string;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!foundExistingCSV) user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      }
      user.markModified('csv_files');
      user.save();

      return res.sendStatus(204);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did add `return` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: can you also try to change `status` to `sendStatus`. I updated the code above.